# Display list items with custom separator using print() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, argument-unpacking

Can someone explain to me why when I'm trying to pass unpacked data into print function using asterisk, the optional argument "end" is applied only for the last list's element, and for the rest is default (space)

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(*l, end='-')
```

I expected `a-b-c-` instead of `a b c-`

Comment: As the name implies the `end` character is placed at the end of what you print, the very end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`print()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print),

> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by `sep` and followed
>   by `end`.
>
> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does and
>   written to the stream, separated by `sep` and followed by `end`.

The `sep` argument is used to control the separator between arguments to `print`. `end` just controls the line terminator.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(*l, sep='-', end='-')
# a-b-c-
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answer, you may find the following useful as well:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print('-'.join(l) + '-')
a-b-c-
```

Comment: That's pretty much what `print` does internally for convenience.